# Wordpress - Bootstrap Alignment

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, blogs

I am currently working on a hacked together wordpress site for a freelance client and am having a major issue with their blog section. The 3rd row of the blog section is bumping down to 2 rows. Any advice or help is much appreciated.

Here is the link: http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/ if you click blog at the top it'll scroll you down to the section in which I'm referring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with bootstrap when you have multiple columns wrapping in a single row. In your case, it is happening due to the fact that not all of your blog columns are the same height. In this instance, "How Porcelain Veneers Can Improve Your Smile" is 542px high while almost everything else if 521px high.

If you set a max height to 521px of your blog sections the problem is resolved. See screenshot below:

[image]

A useful tool for solving invisible layout problems is the 3D view tool for firefox. You can learn more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View

Comment: No problem! If you found this answer helpful please accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to clear the columns float at the correct breakpoint since you have columns of varying heights. See [MDN Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) you can also read about Bootstraps built-in clearing utilities here: [Resets](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets).

**Note:** You'll want to make sure to only appy this to areas of the grid you want to clear so use specification to declare this or add an additional class if you need to.

`col-md-4` implies nth-child(3n+1) @ above 991px so:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  #blog .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

Working Example:

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800";
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,300";
 html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
  font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility!important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.64285;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: auto;
  position: relative
}
a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #39adff;
  outline: 0
}
section {
  position: relative
}
.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center center
}
.fullwidth-section {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px
}
.kill-top-margin {
  margin-top: 0!important
}
.kill-bottom-margin {
  margin-bottom: 0!important
}
.kill-top-padding {
  padding-top: 0!important
}
.kill-bottom-padding {
  padding-bottom: 0!important
}
.img-center {
  margin: 0 auto
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 1000px!important
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #39adff
}
h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 30px
}
h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 24px
}
h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 18px
}
h5,
.h5 {
  font-size: 14px
}
h6,
.h6 {
  font-size: 12px
}
img,
.wp-post-image {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.img-thumb {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.img-float-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%
}
.img-float-right {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%
}
.img-outline {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #39adff;
  background-color: #FFF
}
.img-hover {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -moz-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s
}
.img-hover:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.img-hover i {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -18px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all .55s;
  -moz-transition: all .55s;
  -o-transition: all .55s;
  transition: all .55s
}
.img-hover:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1
}
.img-hover i:hover {
  color: #39adff;
  background-color: #FFF
}
.blog-img-wrapper .img-thumb {
  height: 250px
}
.blog-img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.blog-hover {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 3px solid #39adff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .45s;
  -moz-transition: all .45s;
  -o-transition: all .45s;
  transition: all .45s;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.blog-hover i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 1px
}
.blog-hover-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s
}
hr.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.blog-hover-buttons a {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s
}
.blog-hover-buttons a:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #39adff;
  border: 1px solid #FFF
}
.blog-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1
}
.blog-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}
#blog h6 {
  font-weight: 400
}
#blog-posts h2 a,
#blog-posts h2 a:visited,
#blog-posts-masonry h4 a,
#blog-posts-masonry h4 a:visited,
#blog h4 a,
#blog h4 a:visited {
  color: #39adff
}
#blog-posts h2 a:hover,
#blog-posts h2 a:active,
#blog-posts-masonry h4 a:hover,
#blog-posts-masonry h4 a:active,
#blog h4 a:hover,
#blog h4 a:active {
  color: #555
}
#blog-posts hr {
  margin-bottom: 40px
}
#blog-posts .blog-img-wrapper .img-thumb {
  height: 450px
}
.img-overlay1:after {
  background: url(../img/pat1.png) repeat;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5
}
.img-overlay2:after {
  background: url(../img/pat2.png) repeat;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5
}
.img-overlay3:after {
  background: url(../img/pat3.png) repeat;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5
}
.img-overlay4:after {
  background: url(../img/pat4.png) repeat;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5
}
.transparent {
  background: transparent!important
}
.img-overlay-solid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
.blogbutton {
  float: right;
  background-color: #3071a7;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.blogbutton a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  #blog .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="blog">
  <div class="fullwidth-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class=" kill-top-margin uppercase">The Dental Blog</h1>
          <div style="font-size: 18px" class="weight-400"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/are-dental-implants-in-your-future/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bigstock-Dental-Implant-detailed-view-39564646small-1140x632.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bigstock-Dental-Implant-detailed-view-39564646small-433x433.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/are-dental-implants-in-your-future/">Are Dental Implants in Your Future?</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on May 5, 2016</h6>
            <p>Dental implants: they&#8217;re not just for grandma anymore! The dental implant market is exploding with a growth rate of 9.7 percent between 2014 and 2020. Why this sudden boom? One major reason is that the materials and technology behind
              implants &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/are-dental-implants-in-your-future/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/are-dental-implants-in-your-future/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/dental-sealants-101/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dental-sealants.png" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dental-sealants.png');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/dental-sealants-101/">Dental Sealants 101</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on April 27, 2016</h6>
            <p>The majority of children who regularly visit the dentist will have dental sealants placed on their back teeth while they are still very young. If your dentist has made mention of dental sealants, you may have some questions about what &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/dental-sealants-101/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/dental-sealants-101/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/palatal-expanders-what-they-help-and-how/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/0807151021-1140x641.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/0807151021-433x433.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/palatal-expanders-what-they-help-and-how/">Palatal Expanders: What They Help&#8230; and How</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on April 20, 2016</h6>
            <p>You may think of your child&#8217;s orthodontist as someone who has the ability to reposition crooked teeth, but did you know that they can also expand an individual&#8217;s upper jaw? Through the usage of palatal expanders, orthodontists
              have the ability &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/palatal-expanders-what-they-help-and-how/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/palatal-expanders-what-they-help-and-how/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/cosmetic-dentistry-and-the-holy-grail-of-the-perfect-smile/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/CosmeticDentistry.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/CosmeticDentistry-433x320.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/cosmetic-dentistry-and-the-holy-grail-of-the-perfect-smile/">Cosmetic Dentistry and the Holy Grail of the Perfect Smile</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on April 13, 2016</h6>
            <p>What is it that attracts you to others? If you&#8217;re like most people, you&#8217;re drawn to and captivated by a dazzling smile. People who smile big for all the world to see are happy, vibrant, and confident. Why? Because they &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/cosmetic-dentistry-and-the-holy-grail-of-the-perfect-smile/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/cosmetic-dentistry-and-the-holy-grail-of-the-perfect-smile/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/how-porcelain-veneers-can-improve-your-smile/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/how-to-whiten-porcelain-veneers.png" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/how-to-whiten-porcelain-veneers-433x433.png');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/how-porcelain-veneers-can-improve-your-smile/">How Porcelain Veneers Can Improve Your Smile</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on April 6, 2016</h6>
            <p>We all want healthy teeth. Good oral hygiene, after all, impacts all aspects of health and longevity. But just because your mouth is free from any cavities or gum disease doesn’t necessarily guarantee that your teeth are attractive. For one
              &#8230;
            </p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/how-porcelain-veneers-can-improve-your-smile/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/how-porcelain-veneers-can-improve-your-smile/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/a-few-simple-ways-to-protect-your-childrens-teeth/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/child-at-dentist-small.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/child-at-dentist-small-433x433.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/a-few-simple-ways-to-protect-your-childrens-teeth/">A Few Simple Ways to Protect Your Children&#8217;s Teeth</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on March 31, 2016</h6>
            <p>By the time your child hits the age of 12 or 13 years old, his or her adult teeth will have all settled in for a permanent stay. This means that as a parent, you only have a few years &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/a-few-simple-ways-to-protect-your-childrens-teeth/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/a-few-simple-ways-to-protect-your-childrens-teeth/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-2-of-2/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/toothache.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/toothache-433x433.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-2-of-2/">10 Common Causes of Toothaches, part 2 of 2</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on March 23, 2016</h6>
            <p>Few things can be as annoying or interruptive as a toothache. When the pain is severe, it&#8217;s often difficult to go about your daily routine. It&#8217;s been known to bring even the toughest men and women to their knees, and &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-2-of-2/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-2-of-2/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-1-of-2/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/man-toothache-1140x760.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/man-toothache-433x433.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-1-of-2/">10 Common Causes of Toothaches, part 1 of 2</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on March 17, 2016</h6>
            <p>Anyone who has ever had a toothache can tell you that it&#8217;s not pleasant. In fact, the pain of a toothache can get so intense that it&#8217;s difficult to even think straight at times. When you experience a toothache, it &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-1-of-2/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/10-common-causes-of-toothaches-part-1-of-2/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="blog-img-wrapper">
            <div class="blog-hover">
              <div class="blog-hover-buttons">
                <a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/bad-breath-doesnt-have-to-ruin-your-day/"><i class="im-redo2"></i></a>
                <a data-pp="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bad-breath-1140x760.jpg" title=""><i class="im-expand2"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bad-breath-433x433.jpg');">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-text">
            <h4><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/bad-breath-doesnt-have-to-ruin-your-day/">Bad Breath Doesn&#8217;t Have to Ruin Your Day</a></h4>
            <h6>by Bruce McArthur DDS on March 10, 2016</h6>
            <p>We all want to think that our breath smells just wonderfully, but the truth is that millions of people experience bad breath every day. The problem is that it&#8217;s difficult to know when you have bad breath until someone points &#8230;</p>
            <h6 class="pull-left"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/bad-breath-doesnt-have-to-ruin-your-day/#respond ">No Comment</a></h6>
            <h6 class="pull-right"><a href="http://brucemcarthurdentistrylakewood.com/bad-breath-doesnt-have-to-ruin-your-day/">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h6>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blogbutton">
        <a href="/blog/"> View All Posts </a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</section>
```